# ¿Cómo generar controles dinamicamente en Angular?

Tags: asp.net, angular

mi pregunta es, ¿hay alguna librería que permita generar controles de manera dinamica en Angular? Me refiero a, extraigo x cantidad de registros de la BD, entre esos campos hay de tipo string, fecha, números, etc. ¿Hay alguna librería que permita generar los controles respectivos al tipo de dato que se extrae de la base de datos, es decir, si extraigo una fecha, que genere un input del tipo fecha, si el tipo es entero, que genere el input de tipo número y así sucesivamente? Para el backend uso ASP.NET, hay maneras de hacerlo manualmente, pero quería saber si existe alguna librería para ello.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Por qué no controlas los datos con el `typeof`? No sé, no me ha quedado clara la pregunta :)

Comment: No sé que entendiste jejejeje, pero ahí especifique un poco más la pregunta! Gracias!

Comment: Vale, no estoy capacitado para responder a eso xD

Comment: Jejeje no hay problema, ya aparecerá alguien que sepa algo!